# Function to validate the size of a text entered by user c++

Tags: c++

I have tried the Function below ,

```
string checkstring(int sublen){

bool quit = false;

string temp;
while(!quit){
     cin>>temp;

    if (temp.size()> sublen){
        cout<<"\t"<<"Error , Only "<<sublen<<"characters are allowed "<<endl;

         cin.clear();
          getch();
    }else{
        return temp;
        quit=true;
    }
}
}
```

The Problem is , if i enter any digit in the input string , it skips few lines.

Ex :-
 Enter Your Last Name : Mayer 23,

it Skips next question from the loop

[Question Marked with blue has skipped - Please view thus image | Cursor at Red Mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD4ZV.png)

Sorry About my bad English ! Please Help!

Comment: Please don't post/link to images. Provide the info as *text* instead - directly *in* the question. Also, your example would be better if it was complete and compilable.

Comment: What's your `main` consist of?

Comment: Your function seems to return nothing, even if your code says it should return a `string`.

Comment: `while(!uufname)
{
   cout<<"\t"<<"\t"<<" Enter User First Name :  " <<"\t";
   ufname = checkstring(20);
    uufname = true;
}`

LIke this

Comment: Don't mix C input/output functions like `getch` with C++ stream operations. Use one or the other. The C input/output functions from `stdin` and to `stdout` are by default synchronized with the corresponding C++ streams `std::cin` and `std::cout`, but I'd still recommend against mixing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read text using the `>>` operator, it separates on *white-space*. If you want a whole line use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.